# How to merge two columns of a dataframe based on values from a column in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called df_location:

```
location = {'location_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            'temperature_value': [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29],
            'humidity_value':[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69]}
df_location = pd.DataFrame(locations)
```

I have another dataframe called df_islands:

```
islands = {'island_id':[10,20,30,40,50,60],
          'list_of_locations':[[1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9],[10]]}
df_islands = pd.DataFrame(islands)
```

Each island_id corresponds to one or more locations. As you can see, the locations are stored in a list.
What I'm trying to do is to search the list_of_locations for each unique location and merge it to df_location in a way where each island_id will correspond to a specific location.

Final dataframe should be the following:

```
merged = {'location_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'temperature_value': [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29],
                'humidity_value':[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69],
                'island_id':[10,20,20,30,30,40,40,40,50,60]}
df_merged = pd.DataFrame(merged)
```

I don't know whether there is a method or function in python to do so. I would really appreciate it if someone can give me a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `df.apply()`  method works here. It's a bit long-winded but it works:

```
df_location['island_id'] = df_location['location_id'].apply(
    lambda x: [
        df_islands['island_id'][i] \
        for i in df_islands.index \
        if x in df_islands['list_of_locations'][i]     
   
        # comment above line and use this instead if list is stored in a string
        # if x in eval(df_islands['list_of_locations'][i])        
        ][0]
)
```

First we select the final value we want if the if statement is True: `df_islands['island_id'][i]`

Then we loop over each column in `df_islands` by using `df_islands.index`

Then create the if statement which loops over all values in `df_islands['list_of_locations']` and returns `True` if the value for `df_location['location_id']` is in the `list`.

Finally, since we must contain this long statement in square brackets, it is a list. However, we know that there is only one value in the list so we can index it by using `[0]` at the end.

I hope this helps and happy for other editors to make the answer more legible!

```
print(df_location)

   location_id  temperature_value  humidity_value  island_id
0            1                 20              60         10
1            2                 21              61         20
2            3                 22              62         20
3            4                 23              63         30
4            5                 24              64         30
5            6                 25              65         40
6            7                 26              66         40
7            8                 27              67         40
8            9                 28              68         50
9           10                 29              69         60
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. I tried your solution however I'm getting this error.  "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int". The problem I guess is in the index

Comment: Try and use `if int(x) in [int(j) for j in df_islands['list_of_locations'][i]]` in the final bit of the long statement

Comment: It pops up another error " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[' ".

Comment: I think that you must have made a typo somewhere since it is recognising `'[`' as a character when it is actually used to define the boundaries of a list

Comment: @aboudiShukor - I've edited the answer now - it was not clear that your datatype was a string that looked like a list

Answer (score 0):

The pandas method you're looking for to expand your `df_islands` dataframe is `.explode(column_name)`. From there, rename your column to `location_id` and then join the dataframes using `pd.merge()`. It'll perform a SQL-like join method using the location_id as the key.

```
import pandas as pd

locations = {'location_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            'temperature_value': [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29],
            'humidity_value':[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69]}
df_locations = pd.DataFrame(locations)

islands = {'island_id':[10,20,30,40,50,60],
          'list_of_locations':[[1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9],[10]]}
df_islands = pd.DataFrame(islands)

df_islands = df_islands.explode(column='list_of_locations')

df_islands.columns = ['island_id', 'location_id']

pd.merge(df_locations, df_islands)
```

```
Out[]:
  location_id  temperature_value  humidity_value  island_id
0           1                 20              60         10
1           2                 21              61         20
2           3                 22              62         20
3           4                 23              63         30
4           5                 24              64         30
5           6                 25              65         40
6           7                 26              66         40
7           8                 27              67         40
8           9                 28              68         50
9          10                 29              69         60
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When I'm using the explode method , the column is not unnesting the list no idea why. Any clue what could be wrong ?

Comment: That's odd. Are you getting some sort of error message? If you query `type(df_islands.iloc[0,1])` is the result `list`?

Comment: No. The result is a string not a list.

Comment: For example I typed df_islands.iloc[0,1], it gave me as a result: '[1]'

Comment: That's the issue: so what you have is a string and not a list. Is everything in your dataframe a string type? Implement some type conversions before populating your dataframe so that the location_id, temp_value, and humidity_value are type int, and your list_of_locations is a type list of type ints.

Comment: you can use eval() to  do this btw, calling `eval('[[1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9],[10]]')` will return your string object as a list